# Django: trying to understand how the queryset attribute works in class-based generic views

Tags: python, django, generics

When using class-based generic views in Django, having a `queryset` attribute means to "restrict" the collection of object the view will operate on, right?

> If queryset is provided, that queryset will be used as the source of objects. ([Django's get_object()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object))

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = False
```

View:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Person

class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Person.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

The `queryset` above makes sure to only consider objects with `is_active=true`.

But how does this works internally?

For example: Does Django appends a SQL condition `AND is_active=TRUE` to every query in the view?

Ok that last example seems pretty stupid but I hope you get the idea of my question. Thank you.

Comment: "*Does Django appends a SQL condition AND is_active=TRUE to every query in the view*". Yes, exactly. It then [applies additional filters to narrow down to a specific object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L38).

Comment: @solarissmoke thank you for your comment. If you formulate an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what happens. Your queryset is used as the base queryset by the view's `get_object` method. It then applies an [additional filter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L38) to get a specific object (e.g., by ID):

```
queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
```

Of course, the view needs a single object, not a queryset, so it then does:

```
obj = queryset.get()
```

Which will either return a single object, or a `DoesNotExist` or `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception. `DoesNotExist` results in a 404. `MultipleObjectsReturned` is unhandled and will propagate to your code.